# How to do a full screen in devextreme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, devexpress, devextreme

How to do a full screen in devextreme. For example, take a button next to the screen. And when we click on the button, you get full screen. When you touch the back button, exit the full screen. Is this possible ?

These arrows point in the direction. Upstairs and downstairs

Comment: I guess this is what you're looking for:  [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) or [Featherlight](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/). It's a plugin that makes it possible to display your image in a lightbox.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. Upper base and lower base disappear

Comment: do you have any code to show us?

Comment: No, because I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Popup widget](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxPopup/Configuration/#fullScreen) of DevExtreme has a fullscreen property and [ASPxSplitter](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxNavigationAndLayoutDemos/Splitter/FullscreenMode.aspx) of DevExpress has a FullScreenMode too. Can these help you?

Comment: ASPxSplitter is not relаted with DevExtreme. It's ASP.NET control.

Comment: I do not use popups. When you turn the phone, DxDataGrid becomes small because of the navbar lord. I wanted to translate the navbar with the help of a lost button

Comment: What if you set the dxDataGrid properties width and height to 100% and put it in a <div> container with the following properties
(position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 10) ? Also check this out http://jsfiddle.net/pwLnv121/1/